# Copper plating, is sulphuric acid necessary? Alternative to H2SO4?

Tags: electroplating

Many links and tutorials on copper plating use a solution that contains copper sulphate / sulphuric acid and hydrocloric acid.

In Sweden, Sulphuric acid is almost impossible to get a hold off. You need a license to buy it, and it costs 100 USD to get one...

What does the H2SO4 do in the electrolyte? Is there an alternative to the acid?

I want to plate PCB copper clads.

Comment: Try plating without an acid, and you'll see why it was important. I bet copper will deposit anyway, but will be all spongy and soft.

Comment: Usually you can buy 36% $\ce{H2SO4}$ where you would get lead acid batteries. Isn't it the case in Sweden? As a last resort, buy the lead acid battery and pour the acid out of the cells (be careful though).

Answer (score 1):

[Copper acetate can be used](http://www.instructables.com/id/High-Quality-Copper-Plating/), at least for a thin layer, and it can be made with chemicals found at home.

To get a bright copper coat, extra acid (vinegar, 5% acetic acid, in this case) or [gelatin](http://electroplating-process.blogspot.com/2008/06/addition-agents.html) can be added.

That said, if the plating is for through-hole continuity, it might be simpler and cheaper to use a [solderable conductive ink](https://www.novacentrix.com/products/metalon-inks).